# I'm trying to undo a filter result if I click on the same button again

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I'm trying to undo a filter result if I click on the same button again. My goal is to filter an array and check for if a word has a number of characters, and a few other filters. The problem is that once I filter that array, is there a way to go back and revert the filteredArray to it's previous case?

Here is my current code

```
Class FilterClas {

 var filteredArray = [InfoObject]()
 var isChecked = false 

@IBAction func filterArray(_ sender: Any) {
     if !isChecked {
        isChecked = true


        filteredArray = filteredArray.filter({ m in m.firstImg.characters.count < 160})
        print(filteredArray)
         }
      } else {
        isChecked = false
 // What do I do here to revert the changes I made to the array. 
      }
     }
   }
```

Let me know if anyone needs any more clarification.

Comment: You'll need to separately store the original array.

Comment: That would be a great solution and definitely the simplest if I just wanted to use one filter but as I keep using different filters and add on top of them, I would not be able to do that. It would make it so I would have to start from the begging every time, and I would not be able to access the previous filters I did.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Whenever one of the filters change, reapply them all. If you have such a massive list or such complex filters that it'll cause performance issues, you need to address the design choice that caused that issue. But there's no notion of "revert a var to its previous value", unless you have another backing variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make some of the other answers and comments concrete, you can keep track of your filters and apply them all as needed. For example:

```
class Filter {
    var array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    var filters: [(Int) -> Bool] = []

    var filteredArray: [Int] {
        var filteredArray = array
        for filter in filters {
            filteredArray = filteredArray.filter(filter)
        }
        return filteredArray
    }
}

let f = Filter()
f.filteredArray
f.filters.append { $0 < 8 }
f.filteredArray
f.filters.append { $0 % 2 == 0 }
f.filteredArray
f.filters.append { $0 > 2 }
f.filteredArray
```

Or if you wanted to be able to turn on and off individual filters, you might do it this way:

```
struct Filter {
    let filter: (Int) -> Bool
    var enabled: Bool
}

class Filtered {
    var array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    var filters: [Filter] = [
        Filter(filter: { $0 < 8 }, enabled: true),
        Filter(filter: { $0 % 2 == 0 }, enabled: false),
        Filter(filter: { $0 > 2 }, enabled: true),
    ]

    var filteredArray: [Int] {
        var filteredArray = array
        for filter in filters {
            if filter.enabled {
                filteredArray = filteredArray.filter(filter.filter)
            }
        }
        return filteredArray
    }
}

let f = Filtered()
f.filteredArray
f.filters[1].enabled = true
f.filteredArray
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. It really helped me out. I've been playing around with this put can't figure one thing out. I want to change that struct to be a Dictionary in stead of an array. I've tried different variations but can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "change that struct to be a dictionary instead of an array." What problem are you running into?

Comment: So right now I'm having to reference the filter like f.filter[1].enabled. I want to be able to access via a dictionary and do something like f.filter[filter1].enabled = true. As I get into even more filter in the 45 range, I feel like a Dictionary would be a better way to access the filter. Does it make any more sense what I am asking?

Comment: Sure; that's no problem. You just want `var filters: [String: Filter]` instead? That seems straightforward.

Comment: Thank You. Ya I was trying to change the Filter Struct and had problems. Yep this makes way more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that you could revert the array to its previous form.

In the code you are overriding the value of `filtered` array with a new array. Remember, `filter` returns a new array, it does not modify the existing one. Therefore, the non-filtered array is already destroyed.

What you could do, would be to store a filtered array an a unfiltered array. This way, when the filter is unchecked, you use the unfiltered one.

This could be seen in the following code:

```
Class FilterClass {

    //unfilteredArray would never be modified
    var unfilteredArray = [InfoObject]()
    //currentArray is the one you are currently using, filtered or not
    var currentArray = [InfoObject]()
    var isChecked = false 

    @IBAction func filterArray(_ sender: Any) {
        if !isChecked {
            isChecked = true
            currentArray = unfilteredArray.filter({ m in m.firstImg.characters.count < 160})
        } else {
            isChecked = false
            currentArray = unfilteredArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really the answer I want, but you gave me a better understanding that the filteredArray is being destroyed. The problem with this is that I have like 30 buttons where you can further filter the list. If I did it this way, I would go back to the original array and lose all of the other filters that I had done. Maybe I need to rethink my architecture and figure out if there is a better way to do this.